# Generator requirement tool accuracy

Tags: power-supply, generator, watts, power-generation

I am building the below web application to publish for free in order to help people individuals calculate what size generator they might need in order for their specific needs.

My question is whether the results shown in the app are correct from and electrical engineering point of view?

http://generator-calculator.com/

*My basic calculation is based on:
(Appliance with the highest starting wattage
+ Total running wattage for all other appliances) = 
Total wattage needed*

Comment: I don't think an electric clothes dryer draws 5.4kW. That is way above what a standard outlet can provide in any country I know of

Comment: @bitshift - Thanks! The exact wattage of individual appliances may not been exactly representative currently, will definitely work to improve that, if the final result is correct based on the presumption is what is key for me at the moment.

Comment: `Review the technical details of my site` sounds like a task for a *paid* contractor. If you would like us to review your approach, you should provide the details of your calculation and some examples using your current data. Otherwise, this question will be useless if the linked site stops working/goes away.

Comment: Not gonna chase a web link.  Describe what you want to know HERE.  Closing until then.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Understand what you are saying completely, the calculation is listed as above. The reason I added the link to my application is to ensure the accumulation of appliances side by side is correct. I believed this was demonstrated a lot more clearly by the app than I could describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a practical example. If we have:

- Appliance A: 2kW in use, 3kW when starting
- Appliance B: 1kW in use, 2.5kW when starting
- Appliance C: 1kW in use, 1kW when starting

Your result would be: 3kW *(Appliance with the highest starting wattage: A)* + (1kW + 1kW) *(Total running wattage for all other appliances: B and C)* = 5kW.

But it is obvious that the worst case here (**if we assume only one starting appliance at a given time**, as you seem to do) is actually 2kW *(A running)* + 2.5kW *(B starting)* + 1kW *(C running)* = 5.5kW.

So the correct formula would actually be something like: *sum of all appliances running power + highest value of {difference between starting/running powers of each appliance}*. Or, to put it differently: *starting power of the appliance with biggest running/starting power difference + running power of all other appliances*.

Now, in case of power outage, you have a problem with this logic anyway: because obviously, all appliances will be re-starting at the same time.

<sub>Edit and disclaimer: I totally agree with Olin, and did not actually even had a look at the link you provided before answering. I assumed all required information was in the question. If it's not the case, my answer may be totally irrelevant.</sub>

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. You may notice that I do include this figures also for a 'maximum wattage' which shows the worse case scenario as you describe. The reason I didn't want to give the max wattage as a recommendation as it would be overkill in a lot of cases. I may need to add a note to explain that the recommended wattage assumes only one application will be started at a time.